# How often can I activate Windows 7 Enterprise?

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When reinstalling Windows 7, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-reinstalling-windows-7-does-the-language-version-architecture-64-bit-or)

Today I installed Windows 7 Enterprise and activated it.

But I got a critical error (Blue Screen of Death) and I formatted and installed Windows again. Does this count as another activation?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, as long as it is the same computer you can install it as often as you want. It's when you try activating it on other computers that you will start getting problems.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows product key is tied to several hardware components. The most important of these components is actually the MAC ID of the network adapter used to connect to the Internet. As long as you have not changed this device there is little chance you will have problems activating your license.

If you do have issues getting it activated, call the phone number you are directed to during the activation process. It is a simple process of activating Windows via the manual phone method. Either way, not an issue.

For the Blue Screen problem it is most likely caused by a driver. If it happens again download [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) and when you run it, the application will scan your crash files and list the most likely culprit in pink. If it is a graphics related file, update your video card drivers. If it is a network related driver, update your network drivers, etc.